# Good sources of filament "sampler" pack?

Tags: filament

The local stores have started to stop selling filaments in the smaller 0.5 kg spools, and it's getting harder to maintain an assortment without buying lots of big spools.

I mainly just want a bunch of different colors (red, black, blue, green, etc.), ideally as a bunch of small spool "samples" or like a "sampler pack". -- Even if they're at .25 kg spool sizes... -- I don't want to spend a ton of money on buying and storing a ton of 1.0kg - 2.0kg spools.

I prefer to print in PLA, but ABS is fine.  I can only print 1.75mm filament.

The seller should to be able to ship to western US, and have filament of decent quality that's not going to ruin my printer.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Are you close to a Fry's Electronics

Comment: I voted to close this question as it asks for a product recommendation, and as such is "too opinion based". This is a very subjective question, and it is not constructive (as answers will have very little, if any objective basis for making their recommendation). Please see the [help center](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for what kinds of question you can ask on this site.

Comment: And as demonstrated by @Carl_Witthoft, this question will attract (solely) link-only answers which will become obsolete as products enter and leave the market.

Comment: Hi BrainSlugs83! Tom is right, and I will therefore have to close your question. Good luck.

Comment: Guess I'm not sure I follow the logic -- most of the 3d printing stuff we discuss at all is going to become obsolete as products enter and leave the market -- it will just take longer to happen. -- Anyway, the answer ended up being useful to me, so I marked it. -- Hope that's alright. :-)

Comment: A non-product-specific solution would be to go in with a friend(s) on some -- buy full rolls together, then either pass them around if you're local, or divide up each roll. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B019PGZQO4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), of course.   I found a pack of 20 colors, maybe 50g each or so, 1.75 PLA. (that link is direct to this product).

#### edit:

Well, dang,  I blinked at that particular item is off the list.  Here are two other multicolor packages currently available (2PM EDT 20 Oct 2016)

[one](https://smile.amazon.com/Ladior-3D-Pen-Filament-Refills/dp/B01I40VQXW/ref=sr_1_3?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1476986079&sr=1-3&keywords=1.75%20PLA%20multicolor) , and  ...    [two](https://smile.amazon.com/Tictop-Printer-Filament-Refills-Environmentally/dp/B00ZTXWLP0/ref=sr_1_15?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1476986079&sr=1-15&keywords=1.75%20PLA%20multicolor)

Comment: Ok, why the downvote?  For that matter, why the downvote on the original without either a comment or a close vote?

Comment: My guess is because you linked to a product that is no longer sold and the original post has 2 close votes.

Comment: Dunno! -- It wasn't me. -- I upvoted though to counteract. -- I can't see the close votes, but no one has commented on my question either, just down voted it. -- Seems like it should be a very easy question to answer too. -- Though 32' seems awfully short for a printer; it's less than 0.1 kg, so it might be that as well?

Comment: I didn't buy directly from the links you provided, but I purchased the products (from other sellers on eBay and Amazon). -- This was really helpful.  Thanks. :-)